# Display duplicate column values as header and other data below respective header

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, duplicates, categories

[this is my database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c49du.png)

I want to the displayed result to look somthing like

I want to display the repeated catagory values as the header with the subcatagory data below the respective catagory. I am using mysqli and keep having the catagory's repeat with every sub catagory.

this is the code I have now

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
mysqli_select_db($conn, "storepos");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM catagorydb";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo "<ol class='rounded-list'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<li class='level-1'>  
    <div class='level cat_row'>";
    echo $row['catagory'];
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<ol class='level-2'>
    <li>
    <div class='cat_row level'>";
    echo $row['subcatagory'];
    echo "</div></li>";
}
echo "</ol></li></ol>";
mysqli_close($conn);
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can first group all items by its category:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM catagorydb GROUP BY catagory";
```

And then loop over all the categories, and within that loop you can loop over each corresponding subcategory.